# Angular Data Table export to Excel using .withButtons: how to maintain Alternate Row style

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using Angular DataTable to populate the list of data. It has an alternate row background color and border styles defined.

The problem is while exporting this Data table to excel, alternate row style, border styles are lost.It contains only Data.

I am using Data Table buttons for this purpose.
Below is the Code snippet I am using in button Options.

```
this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withFnServerData(serverData)
    .withDataProp('data')
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withOption('paging', true)
    .withOption('autoWidth', false)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withDisplayLength(rowCount)
    .withDOM('lrtip')
.withButtons([
     {
            extend: "excelHtml5",
            filename: "MailItemList",
            text: "<i class='fa fa-file-excel-o'></i>  Excel",
            title: "Mail Item List",
            exportOptions: {                    
                columns:[2,3,4,5,6,7,8.9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
            },
            exportData: { decodeEntities: true }
     }
      ]);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you will need to add the styles in the `.xlsx` manually. The easiest approach is to use the inbuilt styles via the `s` attribute.

eg:

```
.withButtons([{
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        customize: function ( xlsx ){
            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

            // jQuery selector to add a border to the third row
            $('row c[r*="3"]', sheet).attr( 's', '25' );

            // jQuery selector to set the forth row's background gray
            $('row c[r*="4"]', sheet).attr( 's', '5' );
        }
    }
]);
```

I've cooked up a demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pUcKSbjqavCKUN3eIdy1?p=preview

**EDIT**
To stripe alternative rows you can use `$('row:odd c', sheet).attr( 's', '5' );`

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped. Still have to work on alternate row logic. Will post the answer asap.

Comment: List of built in Excel styles - https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Built-in-styles

Comment: Added a jQuery selector for striping alternative rows